# ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CqlStorage using imports:

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

i tried to run this script on the pig in local mode:

```
test = LOAD 'cql://phoenix/simple_table/' USING CqlStorage;
```

But i'm getting this following error,

```
> 2016-05-10 18:28:48,249 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
> - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CqlStorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
> Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig_1462885029564.log
```

I'm using hadoop 2.2.0, cassandra 1.2.4 and pig 0.12.0.

And my bash file is,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PIG_HOME=/home/hduser/pig-0.12.0
export PIG_CONF_DIR=/home/hduser/pig-0.12.0/conf
export PIG_CLASSPATH=/home/hduser/apache-cassandra-1.2.4-src/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=localhost;
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160;
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner;
```

and run this command on pig,

```
register '/home/hduser/apache-cassandra-1.2.4-src/build/apache-cassandra-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar'
define CqlStorage org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlStorage();
```

But i am getting this same error.What's problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have the cassandra jar file in your classpath. That class is included as a part of the distribution.

Here's a tutorial: http://saugereau.github.io/blog/2015/03/cassandra-pig/